# Check if multidimensional array has values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Lets say my ArrayList is:

```
["b1, "b2", "b3"]
```

and my multidimensional array is:

```
[["b", "b2", "b3"], ["b4", "b5", "b6"], ["b7", "b8", "b9"], ["b", "b4", "b7"], ["b2", "b5", "b8"], ["b3", "b6", "b9"], ["b", "b5", "b9"], ["b3", "b5", "b7"]];
```

I want to check if all three values in my ArrayList is also in my multidimensional array.

Comment: not clear to me. you mean if the "tuple" ["b1, "b2", "b3"] is present in the multidimensional array, or if each string is somewhere in the multidimensional array?

Comment: You know you're supposed to submit a code snippet too, right?

Comment: ["b1", "b2", "b3"] is present in the multidimensional array @luksch

Comment: Does order matter? I.e. do you expect `["b2", "b", "b3"]` to return `true` with the given multidimensional array?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, it could be ["b2", "b1", "b3"]  @ Turing85

Comment: So you want like if input is `["b1, "b2", "b3"]` then `["b1, "b2", "b3"]` or `["b2, "b1", "b3"]` should be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem at hand is that order does not matter. To avoid further complication, you can simply "sort" each line within your given array (let's name is `wordsArray2D`), as well as your list (let's call it `wordsList`). Here is a sample implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // This is our "dictionary" of given "lines".
        String[][] wordsArray2D = {{"b1", "b2", "b3"},
                                  {"b4", "b5", "b6"},
                                  {"b7", "b8", "b9"},
                                  {"b", "b4", "b7"},
                                  {"b2", "b5", "b8"},
                                  {"b3", "b6", "b9"},
                                  {"b", "b5", "b9"},
                                  {"b3", "b5", "b7"}};

        // To neglect order, sort each line (since String is Comparable,
        // let's do Array.sort(...) the work for us)
        for (int idx = 0; idx < wordsArray2D.length; ++idx) {
            Arrays.sort(wordsArray2D[idx]);
        }

        // Our input, as List<String>. Add some content
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        wordsList.add("b2");
        wordsList.add("b1");
        wordsList.add("b3");

        // To start form even ground, convert the List into an Object[]...
        Object[] wordsListAsArray = wordsList.toArray();
        // ... and sort it as well. Again - this gets rid of ordering problems.
        Arrays.sort(wordsListAsArray);

        for (String[] wordsArray : wordsArray2D) {
            // Tow String[] are equal, iff their Strings at the correspinding
            // indices are equal. For this, we can use Arrays.equals(...)
            if (Arrays.equals(wordsArray, wordsListAsArray)) {
                System.out.println("found.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.sort(Some collection)` to sort each list in multidimensional array. Later check whether the two lists are same or not using `equals()`

```
    ArrayList all=new ArrayList();

    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("a");
    al.add("b");
    al.add("c");

    ArrayList<String> al1=new ArrayList<String>();
    al1.add("c");
    al1.add("b");
    al1.add("a");

    ArrayList<String> al2=new ArrayList<String>();
    al2.add("a");
    al2.add("c");
    al2.add("b");

    ArrayList<String> al3=new ArrayList<String>();
    al3.add("a");
    al3.add("b");
    al3.add("c");

    all.add(al1);all.add(al2);all.add(al3);

    for(int i=0;i<all.size();i++)
    {
        ArrayList tmp=(ArrayList)all.get(i);
        Collections.sort(tmp);
        if(tmp.equals(al))
        System.out.println(all.get(i));
        //if both are same then do some action here.
    }
```

**Output:**

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
```